# Matching either pattern with re_path in Django 3.0

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm struggling to figure out how to use a regex with re_path in Django to match either of a set of patterns.

I want to match `/bucket/`, `/buckets/`, `/pail/`, or `/pails` to a single view.

In my primary urls file I've got:

```
from bucket import urls as bucket_urls
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^(?:bucket)s?/', include(bucket_urls))
]
```

and in the `bucket.urls` module I have:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("new", views.BucketCreate.as_view(), name="create_bucket"),
    ...
    path('', BucketList.as_view(selection="recent"), name="buckets")
]
```

This works for `/bucket/` and `/buckets/`, as well as `/bucket/new/` and `/buckets/new/` as well as other urls extended from bucket(s).

If I change it to `'^(?:bucket|pail)s?/'` none of the  bucket(s) or pail(s) urls work.

If I change it to `'^(bucket)s?/'` none of the bucket(s) urls work.  If I understand correctly, this is because the () is capturing the `bucket` part and the `?:` stops that?

trying this works

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^buckets?/', include(bucket_urls)),
    re_path(r'^pails?/', include(bucket_urls)),
]
```

but gives this warning: `?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'bucket' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace`

Should I worry about that warning?

Any pointers on how I can match `/bucket/`, `/buckets/`, `/pail/`, or `/pails/` with a single regex so I don't get the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex expression to the following, **`r'^[(bucket|pail)s]+/'`**

```
from django.urls import include, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    re_path(r'^[(bucket|pail)s]+/', include(bucket_urls)),
    ...
]
```

---

To resolve the **`(urls.W005)`** warning specify the [***namespace***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) argument to the [**`include(...)`** (Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#include) function

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^buckets?/', include((bucket_urls, namespace='buckets'))),
    re_path(r'^pails?/', include((bucket_urls, namespace='pails'))),
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the input.  Using the namepace argument took care of what I was after.  The regular express change works to stop the warning, but it makes all my urls from `reverse("buckets:blah")` messy.

Answer (score 1):

You should just specify different [namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces):

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^buckets?/', include((bucket_urls, "buckets"))),
    re_path(r'^pails?/', include((bucket_urls, "pails"))),
]
```

Now you should add this namespace as prefix when you will reverse url e.g.:

```
reverse( 'buckets:index')
```

Otherwise urls from buckets and pails will be clashed and djnago will not kwon wich one to use, so it show this warning.

Comment: Thank you, adding the namespace argument took care of what I was trying to do.